# Paralliize NUnit test cases lower than test fixure level

Tags: c#, optimization, nunit

I'm working on the NUnit test project and trying to making test cases run in parallel.

What I have done so far can only make test fixures run in parallel. However, it is not enough and creates hundreds of fixures that are tedious tasks and hard to maintain.

Is there any better way than creating one fixture for one test case if I want to run all cases in parallel?

AssemplyInfo.cs

```
[assembly: Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)]
[assembly: LevelOfParallelism(12)]
```

Test.cs

```
[TestFixture]
[Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)]
```

Comment: Of course you need to ensure your app is compatible with concurrent testing.  Unless you are mocking (which defeats the purpose of testing anyway), the AUT generally requires a DB where tests expect it to be in a known state.  Concurrent tests breaks that

Comment: This is true. I faced some problems when hitting DB and API but all were solved.

Comment: Great to hear! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run all fixtures in parallel, you only need the assembly level attribute.

```
[assembly: Parallelizable(ParallelScope.All)]
```

You can add `LevelOfParallelism`, but it is better to allow NUnit to set the value based on the number of processors you have.

You only want to set `Parallelizable` on your test classes if you want something different than the global behavior.

Prior to NUnit 3.8, tests were only run in Parallel down to the fixture level. Running test methods in Parallel was adding in NUnit 3.8, but I would recommend moving directly to 3.9 to avoid some parallelization errors that were introduced by the change in 3.8.

Comment: Thanks, Rob, I would like it to run in test cases level which is lower than fixures.

Comment: With NUnit 3.9, the assembly level attribute should run everything in parallel down to the method level. Are you not seeing this? Things like Console.WriteLine() are buffered, so not a true indication of parallel.

Comment: I will update NUnit and try again and will let you know. Thanks.